# Can a jstree node contain dropdown lists?

Tags: .net, asp.net, jquery, jstree

I need to develop a tree structure to edit an XML file and jstree seems to be the best way to do my job. What is the level of customization of a node? Can I use dropdowns to edit a node value? Are there any known limitations I should know of? Does it work fine with ASP.NET?
Thanks!

Comment: Hi, I'll post this link here instead of in an answer, because I don't have enough experience with jstree to answer your question about the dropdown lists. Here it is: http://mohyuddin.blogspot.com/2009/06/binding-jstree-with-database-in-aspnet.html. Good luck!

Comment: thank you! Not what I was looking for, but really helpful anyway